# Error shows "Failed to get text for stylesheet (#): No style sheet with given id found", what does this mean?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm getting this error in Chrome when it loads this application I am working on:

> Failed to get text for stylesheet 50: No style sheet with given id found

Subsequent page loads repeat the error, but with a different number:

> Failed to get text for stylesheet 152: No style sheet with given id found

This only happens in Chrome, and only with this application.  There is no stack trace, reference, or any other information about what id is given, what the stylesheet in question is, or what is causing this generally.  How can I find what is causing this error and fix it?

Comment: Can you post the html for calling the stylesheet?

Comment: Do you have a URL or a CodePen? Are there any scripts running or is this HTML/CSS only issue?

Comment: @Huangism - The html for which stylesheet? This is in an application with dozens of them, referenced with .NET MVC `BundleCollection.Add(new StyleBundle("~/whatever.css"))` statements. I am not getting a 404 error, and I see no other indication which stylesheet Chrome is talking about.

Comment: @philtune - There are scripts in the application, yes. And they appear to be functioning correctly.  Not knowing which segment is causing the issue, I would have to post the entire application, but it is not open-source.

Comment: I get this error as well. Can't see the reason for the down vote. the error is inconsistent and not apparently related to the page - possibly a dev environment (such as Visual Studio with Web Essentials) issue..?

Comment: @Calle - I'm not sure why the downvote either.  The other comments seem to want me to say which stylesheet is causing the issue, but that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out. I am using a Visual Studio debug session, but all the script/style tags on the page look valid.

Comment: I have also started to see this error recently in Chrome.  I have not found any steps to reproduce it consistently.

Comment: It appears to be very inconsistent. I had it happen on several consecutive pages of my ASP.NET MVC app the first time those pages loaded, and then could not reproduce it for 15 minutes and gave up. It reproduced on some very simple pages with almost no javascript. I used Fiddler to see if any different HTTP requests or tunnels were being made when the error occurred versus when it didn't, and I found nothing. It doesn't seem to be causing any real problem, and in fact the console error count shows as 0 even though the error is logged to the console, so I am going to treat as a benign hiccup.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

I had the same problem. It looks like a bug in Chrome's live-edit CSS/JS. Notice how the number changes on each request.

**I fixed it by** closing all the files that I had edited in the dev tools 'source' tab and then refreshed the page.

The error went away after I closed all the files in the 'source' tab.

I tried to reproduce it after closing the files, but I can't seem to recreate it, yet.

---

Here is a picture showing where to find the 'source' tab:

[image]

Comment: Still persits in Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m   :)

Comment: The bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424544 reported as fixed.

Comment: It's fixed in Chrome Canary (40.0.2214.111), but the stable version (currently 41.0.2272.118 m) hasn't got that fix yet.

Comment: Still present in Chrome Stable (46.0.2490.71 (64-bit))

Comment: Still present in Chrome 48.0.2564.23 beta (64-bit)

Comment: Just experienced in Version 47.0.2526.80 (64-bit)

Comment: Still experiencing the issue on Version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit), OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Version 48.0.2564.116 still there but the fix above works

Comment: persists in Opera 35.0.2066.92

Comment: you don't need to close files that aren't CSS

Comment: Chrome ` 49.0.2623.112` still have this issue.

Comment: persistent little bug: Chrome 51.0.2704.104
Also it seems to be quite transient -- typically I only see this every once in a while, and page refreshes seem to get rid of it, but occasionally a page refresh (while debugging lots of js/css open w/ different debugger instances) creates the issue as well. I haven't had to close anything but I suspect that would help as well

Answer (score 1):

Still present in Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m (64-bit).
Closing sources tabs 'fixed' it.

Answer (score 1):

Fixt it by holding [Ctrl] + [Shift] and refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced this today if you have a .css file open in the dev tools. If you close the .css file and reload, the issue does not happen.

Chrome 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit)