# fullcalendar set slotDuration not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

i have a calendar working with the following code:

```
$( document).ready( function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( {
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' },
        editable: true,
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        eventLimit: true,
        events: source
    }
)}
```

Following [this](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/A6ksz/153/) flddle, i tried to set the slotDuration to 15 min, but it's not working. It just uses the default 30 min.

The only hint i get is this error when i open the calendar on Chrome:

```
Failed to get text for stylesheet 37: No style sheet with given id found
```

Any idea of which might be the problem?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894718/error-shows-failed-to-get-text-for-stylesheet-no-style-sheet-with-given-id?

Comment: Are you using fullCalendar 2.x?

Comment: Thanks guys, but i just realized the what the problem was. I'm using vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine gem, which doesn't include all the features of fullcalendar. It even doesn't include locale..