# Load form result inside a loaded file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Good morning. I'm trying to load the response from FORM POST inside my same file.

This is my index:

```
<div class="right-half">
    <div id="include">
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $("#search").click(function(){
            $("#include").load("admin_search.php"); 
        });
        $("#add").click(function(){
            $("#include").load("include/test.html"); 
        });
        $('#user').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('POST'), // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('admin_user.php'), // the file to call
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    $('#include').html(response); // update the DIV
                }
                });
            return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
        });
</script>
```

And this is my admin_search.php file, which in case it's not obvious, it's being loaded by jQuery inside my index file:

```
<section>
<div>
    <header>
        <h2>Buscar información de usuario</h2>
    </header>

    <p>Para buscar un usuario o su información relacionada, ingresa el correo electrónico con el que el usuario se identifica.</p>

    <form id="user">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar usuario">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

In theory, I should be getting the result from admin_user.php inside my #include DIV, but I'm getting nothing.

Could anyone give me some advice on this?

EDIT: Here's my admin_user.php file

```
<?php

require_once('admin_connect.php');
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE email = '$email'");

echo("
<table cellspacing='0'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>VALORES</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>");

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo("
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>"); echo $row['name']; echo("</td>
        </tr><!-- Table Row -->
        <tr class='even'>
            <td>Correo electrónico</td>
            <td>"); echo $row['email']; echo("</td>
        </tr><!-- Darker Table Row -->
        <tr>
            <td>Edad</td>
            <td>"); echo $row['age']; echo("</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='even'>
            <td>Sexo</td>
            <td>"); echo $row['gender']; echo("</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Peso:</td>
            <td>"); echo $row['weight']; echo("</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='even'>
            <td>Estatura</td>
            <td>"); echo $row['height']; echo("</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Problemas de salud</td>
            <td>"); echo $row['health_problem']; echo("</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='even'>
            <td>Actividad física</td>
            <td>"); echo $row['activity']; echo("</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alergias</td>
            <td>"); echo $row['food_sick']; echo("</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>");
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**

I managed to solve it by moving this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#user').submit(function(event) { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $('#user').serialize(), // get the form data
        type: 'POST', // GET or POST
        url: 'admin_user.php', // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('#include').html(response); // update the DIV
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

... to my admin_search.php file.

Then, due some unexpected error, I had to add `crossDomain: true,` to my ajax call, and voila!. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Doesn't seem to be getting a response at all. Yes I have. No there are none. Yes I am.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @u_mulder That broke the admin_search loading.

Answer (score 0):

In your `$.ajax` function, the `type` attribute should just be like this: `type: 'POST'`.  Also the `url` should just be like this: `url: 'admin_user.php'`.  Also not sure if `$(this)` inside your ajax function is referencing the `self` you are thinking of, so I would explicitly change that line to: `$('#user').serialize()`.

ALso you might want to add the `error` function to the `ajax` call.

**EDIT**
You need to run your AJAX function call after loading your form, so this would be inside the `$('#search').click` method, after loading your form.

Altogether it would look like this:

```
$("#search").click(function(){
    $("#include").load("admin_search.php");
    $('#user').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $('#user').serialize(), // get the form data
            type: 'POST', // GET or POST
            url: 'admin_user.php', // the file to call
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                $('#include').html(response); // update the DIV
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
        return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    });
});
```

Comment: Still doing nothing for me :( It works with no problem if I do it the HTML way, but fails to load anything with jQuery.

Comment: @S.Martell Well just noticed in your question that you never closed your `<section>` tag in the `admin_search.php` file.

Comment: I just missed that tag when copy pasting. It is there. I'm not getting any errors, but I'm seeing this: Request Method: Get, on the Headers on the Dev tools. Could that be it?

Comment: Can you include the code from your `admin_user.php` file?  Also if you set a check point inside the `success` function, on the `$('#include').html(response);` line, does your program hit the checkpoint?

Comment: I've added admin_user.php to my original post. I'm going to try the check point.

Comment: It would appear, it's not finding #user at all. This is the error I got: >Failed to get text for stylesheet 1114.137: No style sheet with given id found

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894718/error-shows-failed-to-get-text-for-stylesheet-no-style-sheet-with-given-id looks like a Chrome bug, which isn't necessarily a problem with your program.  So it is hitting the check point in the success funciton?  Also did you add the `error` function to catch errors?

Comment: I did. Still not getting no errors or the data loaded in my div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118356/discussion-between-jeffery-the-wind-and-s-martell).